# DS3231 RTC corruption issue @ reboot with raspberry pi3 on 2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, rtc

I want to interface precision RTC DS3231 with Raspberry Pi3, so that my PI will get accurate time (even in the absence of network). I am using the latest raspbian image 2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie. I could be able to interface DS3231 with raspberry pi. I gets the correct timing when i hwclock -r. But the problems arise, when i reboots.  RTC is getting corrupted to 2066-01-01 after reboots. And i cross checked the RTC with Atmega32 and confirmed that it is working properly. I have tried various methods available in net. I could not make it. Please help. I have connected RPi3 with DS3231 RTC as given below.

BCM 2 (SDA) to SDA

BCM 3 (SCL) to SCL

3.3         to VCC

GND         to GND

i2cdetect output

[image: sudo i2cdetect -y 1 output is this]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your question and include the code you are using, pictures showing all the connections and the output of the following command: sudo i2cdetect -y 1

Comment: Also what are you trying to do?  What are you using the DS3231 for?

Comment: As per joan's comment *"I could not make it"* assumes we are mind readers with regard to what you could not make "it" do.   It appears the RTC is correctly connected and recognized at address 0x68, **so what is your actual problem?**  Please explain 1) What you are trying to do with the clock,  2) How you tried to do it, and 3) What happened that did not meet your expectations.

Comment: **Do not**: 1) Expect other people to bother reading the tutorial material you have read; either cut n' paste the relevant bits or use your own words, 2) Add the material in comments here.  Edit it into the question as you did before (Steve did ask you to include this *all* this information in the first place, not just `i2cdetect` output).

Comment: You still are not doing what I and others ask you to. 1) you are still using the comments to provide additional info when you were asked to edit your question and add those details to your question. 2) where is your code? It should be included above. Without seeing the code you are using we can't help. And your question will never be reopened.

Comment: See the comments on https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=99141. The system calls hwclock early on with --systz which corrupts the registers.

Comment: I disabled ntp server. No more RTC corruption. Even though it won't update RTC time when connected to network, it is OK for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled NTP server. Even though RTC won't get updated when connected to network, RTC is not getting corrupted. I disabled NTP with this command.

```
update-rc.d ntp disable
```